# Why do the filesystems differ in “df” and “fstab?”

Tags: linux, filesystems

I am looking at `/etc/fstab` and the output from `df`. There are far more filesystems under `df`. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because `fstab` is not the only source of mounted partition info. As the man page for [`fstab`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/fstab) explains; bold emphasis is mine:

> The file `fstab` contains descriptive information about the various
>   file systems. **`fstab` is only read by programs, and not written; it
>   is the duty of the system administrator to properly create and
>   maintain this file.**

So `fstab` is basically where user/administrator defined—or at least user/administrator *controllable*—mounts/partitions are managed; the system only reads the `fstab` and does not write to it.

If you want to see what other filesystems and mount points were mounted when the system booted, check the contents of `mtab` like this:

```
cat /etc/mtab
```

Or even `/proc/mounts` like this:

```
cat /proc/mounts
```

Those two files are dynamically created by the system on boot and whenever a new `mount` command is issued. Those files keep track of things that are mounted already and should not be touched by system users/administrators. More details on the [`mount`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) man page.

So knowing that, when you run [`df`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/df)—or `df -h` for human readable output—what you are seeing is a report of *all mounted file systems* disk space usage; not just for items from `fstab` but from *any/all mounted file systems* on the machine.